# Alphanumeric keyboard - javascript - smartclient

Tags: javascript, smartclient

I need to open alphanumeric google keyboard using smart client. I'm just a beginner. Can anyone assist me to create one?

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: NO right now i don't have code